# Function not callable?

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn python and I ran into a problem while writing a simple login page.

```
def Login():
    
    print("Login System")
    print("\n")
    print("1 - Login")
    print("2 - Create an Account")
    PassCheck = False
    UserCheck = False
    Login = False
    selec = input("What do you want to do?: ")

    if selec == '1':
        print("Input your credentials")
        usernameLog = input("Input you username: ")
        usertxt = open("user.txt", "r")
        if usernameLog == usertxt.read():
            UserCheck = True
        else:
            UserCheck = False
            usertxt.close()

        passwordLog = input("Input you password: ")
        passwordtxt = open("pass.txt", "r")
        if passwordLog == passwordtxt.read():
            PassCheck = True
        else:
            PassCheck = False
            passwordtxt.close()
        
        if UserCheck and PassCheck == True:
            print('\n')
            print('\n')
            print('You Logged In')
        else:
            print('\n')
            print('\n')
            print('Username or password incorrect')
            Login()
Login()
```

It was working before and it just stopped working. it says that the Login() function is not callable.

Comment: You created a local variable `Login = False` inside your function, which locally hides the global variable `Login` which is your function.

Comment: the python convention is to use `lowercase_underscore` to name variables and functions, and `CamelCase` for classes. In your code, you are using `Login` for both a function and a variable.

Comment: Delete `Login = False` line!

Comment: Not in the first case i didnt see the recursion

Comment: Oh thanks seems to work now. Dumb mistake...

Comment: Also, don't use recursion here. A loop would be much better.

Comment: Where are you making your `Login = Ture` ?

Answer (score 0):

try to change the name of the variable of Login. and it is better change the name of the function to a lower case.
also try the code below. I just change (if selec == "1") to (if selec == 1)

```
def Login(): 

    print("Login System")
    print("\n")
    print("1 - Login")
    print("2 - Create an Account")
    PassCheck = False
    UserCheck = False

    selec = input("What do you want to do?: ")

    if selec == 1:
        print("Input your credentials")
        usernameLog = input("Input you username: ")
        usertxt = open("user.txt", "r")
        if usernameLog == usertxt.read():
            UserCheck = True
        else:
        UserCheck = False
        usertxt.close()

        passwordLog = input("Input you password: ")
        passwordtxt = open("pass.txt", "r")
        if passwordLog == passwordtxt.read():
            PassCheck = True
        else:
            PassCheck = False
            passwordtxt.close()
    
        if UserCheck and PassCheck == True:
            print('\n')
            print('\n')
            print('You Logged In')
        else:
            print('\n')
            print('\n')
            print('Username or password incorrect')
            Login()

Login()
```

Comment: This doesn't work I am using an input that returns a string.
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/input